# Not Understanting Django Forms and There use, Is there a way to ignore them and still save files uploaded in the forms?

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to make a website using django which I'm not familiar with. Not know what django forms do I wrote my html file purely in html and now I'm having difficulty trying to save uploaded files because django won't let me save them manually. I tried to bypass this with no luck, so I think that now I have to rewrite my html file in django html template, so I can save files. I have an html file like this:

html

```
<div class="w3-container w3-white">
      <select class="w3-select" name="request_function" id="request_function" >
                 <option id="faces_embedding" value="faces_embedding" style="" onclick="pagechange()">faces_embedding</option>
                <!-- <option id="faces_model" value="faces_model" style="" onclick="pagechange()"> faces_model </option> -->
                 <option id="image_recognizer"value="image_recognizer" style="" onclick="pagechange()">image_recognizer</option>
                 <option id="video_recognizer" value="video_recognizer" style="" onclick="pagechange()">video_recognizer</option>
                 <option id="stream_recognition" value="stream_recognition" style="" onclick="pagechange()">stream_recognizer</option>
                 <option id="help" value="help" style="" onclick="pagechange()">help</option>
      </select>
    </div>

<div id="AddFaces" style="visibility: visible; display: block;">
      <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin:0 -16px;" >

            <div class="w3-half">
              <input type="radio" name="input_method" id="input_method_0" onclick="datachange()" checked value="input_method_0">
              <label>Add A Database</label>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-half">
              <input type="radio" name="input_method" id=input_method_1" onclick="datachange()" value="input_method_1">
              <label>Add A Face</label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin:0px -10px;">
            <div id="dataset" class="w3-half w3-margin-bottom" style="visibility: visible; display: block;">
              <label>Dataset Path</label>
              <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="directory path" name="dataset_path" id="dataset_path" required >
            </div>

            <div id="face" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">
            <div  class="w3-half w3-margin-bottom">
              <label>Images Path</label>
              <input type="file" id="face_files" name="face_files" multiple >
            </div>

            <div class="w3-half">
              <label>Name</label>
            <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="person name" name="face_name" id="face_name" >
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

where "datachange()" is a javascript function that hides different dives that I don't need
and my view.py

```
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'index.html')
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = InputForm(request)
        call_form_function(form)
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

where "InputForm.py" is a normal python class which takes forms id tags and use them as input for functions.

```
   def __init__(self, request):
        self.request_function = request.POST.get("request_function")

        self.input_method = request.POST.get('input_method')

        self.dataset_path = request.POST.get('dataset_path')

        self.face_files = request.FILES.getlist['face_files']

        self.face_name = request.POST.get('face_name')
```

from [django documents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/), I used the this function:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

But django automatically close the file before I can write anything.

> QUESTION:
> So my question is that do I have to use django froms to save upload files? Is there a way to bypass this? and If there is no way to do so how can I change my html file in a way that is still looks the same in the webpage and my javascripts work with django templates.
> p.s: I also don't have a database, models.py since I don't have a use for them.

Comment: If you want to build a webapp, no matter which use-case and size, you will need to handle data and thus need a database. Period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you don't use forms and don't use database, why are you using Django :)  As with all modern web frameworks that use MVC (Mode, View, Controller) or in Django case MTV (Model, Template, View) you will sooner or later need all three of those.

Model defines your database schema, Template defines html templates - what users will see, and View is actually where programming logic lives.

If the template has forms, you will need to define form in Django. It actually simplifies life a lot and it can be very simple definition if you use models. And information on your files (metadata) that someone can upload should be stored in a model (database). That will ease your handling of files quite a lot.

But in the end it really depends what is your application doing?

Comment: Initially my work was to just make the functions in InputForm but being a good friend I offered to make it in a Django App since the product was going to be used in a webpage

Comment: If you are using any forms in any web page under Django, you *should* use Django forms, since it will make your life much easier, and it is way how things are done in Django. Everything else is unnecessary complication and doing work arounds.